# Why can't I set my IntVar?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am importing a file that defines a class.  The class has wigits that use an IntVar().  Why can't I set the IntVar?

```
class Config:

    def __init__(self, vector):
        d = 200

        root = Tk()
        print(d)
        size = IntVar()
        size.set(d)
        print(size)
```

Instantiating the class prints the following:

```
200
PY_VAR0
```

Comment: `Py_VAR0` is a reference.  Just use `print(size.get())` instead.

Answer (score 2):

[`StringVar, IntVar, DoubleVar, and BooleanVar`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html) are Tkinter classes having their own methods.  So `print size` means you are printing the reference to `size` variable. If you want to display its value you rather need to use the [`get()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) method.

**Demo:**

```
>>> from Tkinter import *
>>> d = 200
>>> root = Tk()
>>> print d
200
>>> size = IntVar()
>>> size.set(d)
>>> print size.get()
200
>>>
```